# Non instatiable class by deleting destructor?

Tags: c++11, instantiation, deleted-functions

I have a `class` that I use for purely syntactic purposes, to call a function in a certain way. This is a simplified example:

```
#include<iostream>

template<class T1>
struct make{
    template<class T2>
    static T1 from(T2 const& t2){
        return T1{}; //or something more complicated
    }
};

int main(){
    double d = make<double>::from(2);
    std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

Now, suppose I want to warn the user that this class should not be instantiated. **There may be uses for the class to be instatiable but 
 I have the curiosity if it is possible to forbid that?**

First I tried deleting the default constructor

```
template<class T1>
struct make{
    make() = delete;
    template<class T2>
    static T1 from(T2 const& t2){
        return T1{}; //or something more complicated
    }
};
```

But then this is still possible:

```
make<double> m{}; // valid
```

Finally, I tried deleting the destructor and that seemed to work

```
template<class T1>
struct make{
    ~make() = delete;
    template<class T2>
    static T1 from(T2 const& t2){
        return T1{}; //or something more complicated
    }
};
```

But it seems that then the class can still be allocated by `new`.

Should I delete both the destructor and the delete constructor, (what about the copy and move constructor?)

Is this the best way to disallow instantiation?
code here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0299c377c129fffb

```
#include<iostream>

template<class T1>
struct make{
    make() = delete;
    ~make() = delete;
    template<class T2>
    static T1 from(T2 const& t2){
        return T1{}; //or something more complicated
    }
};

int main(){
    double d = make<double>::from(2);
    std::cout << d << '\n';
    make<double> m{}; // compile error (no destructor)
    auto p = new make<double>{}; // compile error (no constructor)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But then this is still possible:
>
> ```
> make<double> m{}; // valid
> ```

... I did not know that would work. But now that I do, I also know *why* it works. And therefore, how to stop it.

It works because `make<T>` as you declared it is an aggregate. Even though it has a deleted default constructor, C++ still considers it an aggregate. And if you use braced-init-lists on an aggregate, you get [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

The way to stop it is simple: make it no longer an aggregate:

```
template<class T1>
struct make{
    template<class T2>
    static T1 from(T2 const& t2){
        return T1{}; //or something more complicated
    }

    make() = delete;

private:
    char c; //Not an aggregate
};
```

That private member forces `make<T>` to no longer be an aggregate. Therefore, it cannot be used with aggregate initialization, so `{}` will attempt to call the default constructor. Which naturally will fail since it's deleted.

Trivially copyable gymnastics might still be used to create instances of `make<T>`. You could shut those down by giving it a `virtual` destructor:

```
template<class T1>
struct make{
    template<class T2>
    static T1 from(T2 const& t2){
        return T1{}; //or something more complicated
    }

    make() = delete;

private:
    char c; //Not an aggregate
    virtual ~make() = default;
};
```

That ought to be sufficient to prevent legal C++ code from creating an object of that type.

Comment: Good insight, but with your code this is still allowed: `auto p = new make<double>;`, it seems that one needs still to delete the constructor (or make it private).

Comment: @alfC: I meant to include deleting the construct. It's just a copy-and-paste error.

Comment: ok, what do you gain by making it a non-agregate once the constructor and the destructors are deleted or declared private?

Comment: @alfC: I explained what you gained. The fact that it's an aggregate is what allowed `make<double>{}` to work even though `make<double>()` did not. By deleting the constructor, you prevent the latter. By making it not an aggregate, you prevent the former. By doing *both*, you prevent all forms of initialization that do not require a pre-existing object of that type (ie: copying/moving).

Comment: I mean that if delete both the constructor and the destructor, also myself forbid `make<double>{}`, no?

Comment: @alfC: No. So long as aggregate initialization is possible, then so too is [`new make<double>{}`](http://rextester.com/LNOD71364). Note that the version of GCC in that live demonstration disagrees, but the standard is *very* clear on this matter. Both Clang and VS compile that just fine. Also, if you delete the destructor, you get a strange and unexpected error. That is, it claims the problem is the deleted destructor. Which it is, but the error the user would expect is the deleted *constructor*. So by making it not an aggregate, you also improve the error messages.

Comment: ok, so my online compiler was giving me a false impression. One needs to 1) delete constructor, 2) making it non-agregate, 3) private the virtual destructor (perhaps deleting the non-virtual contructor works equally well). Perhaps I can also make something `final` to avoid inheritance as well. Perhaps once can make a base class `noninstantiable` like we used to have `boost::noncopyable`.

Comment: @alfC: "*Perhaps I can also make something final to avoid inheritance as well.*" That's pointless, since even if you do make something a base class, you still have to *construct* your base classes. As for making some `noninstantiable`... generally speaking, most people really don't care if you instantiate a class that only contains static members. Doing that doesn't *break* anything. Making a class `noncopyable` was useful since it prevented you from doing something that the class couldn't do.

Comment: `noninstantatiable` would make it more explicit. But I agree that what I am doing could be pointless, and there maybe uses for having instances. The class type can be passed as argument to a function, and that can be useful in itself. `template<class Maker> f(double, Maker){...}` and then `f(5., make<double>{})`.